# How to get a list of G Suite users which are using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I would like to find out, is there any chance to get a list of G Suite users (of one domain) who are using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question, it would be enough to know which users have script projects, and in case if possible to find out when last time it was used. Thanks.

Comment: A bit complicated, but with a service account you could list all users drives querying for files of MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.script` - this will return you all alone-standing Apps Script files, not the ones bound to a document though.

Comment: @ziganotschka - they could also get the list of users (for example, as TheMaster suggest below, from the Directory API), then for each user get a [list of projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects) via Apps Script API. AlexMark, note that you can only get "last updated", you can't get "last ran" info from anywhere.

Comment: @OlegValter: How can you get a list of projects without knowing the scriptid? I don't see this endpoint.

Comment: @ziganotschka I seem to be out of my wits lately, you are right, I forgot `scriptId` has a `required` field set to `true` in the discovery doc, my apologies...

Comment: Will try @ziganotschka suggestion with "MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.script" 

Thanks, ziganotschka, and OlegValter!

Comment: @ziganotschka, oh, I finally found how to combine our suggestions into one for obtaining the most info about projects :) I knew I've seen it somewhere, turned out it was CLASP source for the `list` command: https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/src/commands/list.ts. So, AlexMark, what you need is get the files via ziganotschka's suggestion, extract the script id, using each Id get [processes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes#Process) for each script. What's left is to filter accordingly

Comment: @Oleg Valter I am not familiar with clasp, does it allow you to all user's drive files without a service account? The only problem we still have is too find scripts that are bound e.g. to spreadsheets - those will not show up when querying for `q: 'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.script"'`

Comment: @ziganotschka - now you will be laughing very hard :) It turns out that for script projects file id *is* the scrip Id (you can check on any of your files). So, the files can be retrieved with your method (clasp uses the same method as you do), then processes obtained via API. As for bound scripts - yes, they are a problem, I am not sure if there is a workaround

Comment: I am not sure if I misunderstood the question, but I thought that the OP only wants to know if users have ever used Apps Script. If a suer has a file of MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.script` on his drive - one can assume that he is / was using Apps Script. but once again - this will work only if he has alone-stadnind projects.

Answer (score 3):

### How to verify either domain users have [Standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) Apps Script projects on their Google Drive

1. In order to have as an admin access to your users' Drive, you need to set-up a [service account](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts) in your [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Make sure to enable [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) - this allows oyu to authenticate as a domain user and list his Drive files
3. Go to your [Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) and got to  `Main menu menu> Security > API controls` and add the necessary scopes for the freshly created service account - as described [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)
4. Download the .json file with the service account credentials - it should contain a `"private_key"` field
5. The necessary scope in your case is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`
6. To use a service accounbt within Apps Script, you need to install the OAuth2 for Apps Script library from [as described herehere](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#setup)
7. For this, go to your Apps Script editor, `"Resources > Libraries... > Find a library"` and enter the code `1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF`
8. Chose a version (currently the newest is 38)
9. Now, the first thing you need to do programmaticallyis to enable the [adminSDK](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) to list all domain users  -  as suggested by @TheMaster
10. The second step is to loop through all users, and to create a service account token on their behalf (setting them as a [subject](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth))
11. With the access token you can list the files with the query parameters `q: 'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.script"'` for each user to find out either the user has standaolone Apps Script files on his Drive

**Code sample:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({"domain":"PASTE HERE YOUR DOMAIN NAME"}).users;
  users.forEach(function(user){  
    user = user.primaryEmail;
    getService(user).reset();
    var service = getService(user);
    
    if (service.hasAccess()) {
      Logger.log("service has access");
      var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files";
      var query = '?q=mimeType%3D%22application%2Fvnd.google-apps.script%22';
      var headers ={
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      };       
      var options = {
        'headers': headers,
        'method' : 'get',
        'muteHttpExceptions': true    
      };      
      var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+query, options).getContentText();
      if(JSON.parse(response).files.length==0){
        Logger.log("User " + user + " does not have any Standalone Apps Script projects on his Drive");
      }else{
        Logger.log("User " + user + " has Standalone Apps Script projects on his Drive");
      }
      
    }
    else {
      Logger.log(service.getLastError());
    }
  }
 )
}

var PRIVATE_KEY ="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----PASTE HERE YOUR PRIVATE KEY FROM THE JSON FILE-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
var CLIENT_EMAIL = 'PASTE HERE THE EMAIL OF THE SERVICE ACCOUNT';

function getService(user) {
  return OAuth2.createService('List users')
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
  .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
  .setSubject(user)
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
  .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After you retrieve the list of [script projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#creating_a_project_from_the_script_editor) from Google Drives of your users, you will have to first request project metadata for them from the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects). Presently, the only way to get a project is to go one by one, supplying requests with `scriptId`.

The trick is that the Id of the script project *file* happens to be the *the same* as script Id (if you look at the source code of the CLASP project's `list` command, you will see that they [utilize this fact](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/src/commands/list.ts) to display project Ids).

To acquire a `Project` resource, we need to call the `get` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/get):

```
GET https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{scriptId}
```

Below is a simple utility for retrieving a single `Project` resource from the API. Note that your manifest file will have to include at least the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects.readonly` scope, otherwise the API will return a `403` response code.

```
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *  domain : string,
 *  email : string,
 *  name : string
 * }} GSuiteUser
 * 
 * @typedef {{
 *  scriptId : string,
 *  title : string,
 *  createTime : string,
 *  updateTime : string,
 *  creator : GSuiteUser,
 *  lastModifyUser : GSuiteUser
 * }} ScriptProject
 * 
 * @summary gets script project metadata
 * @param {{
 *  id : string,
 *  token : string
 * }}
 * @returns {ScriptProject}
 */
const getProject = ({
  id = ScriptApp.getScriptId(),
  token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
}) => {

  const uri = `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${id}`;

  /** @type {GoogleAppsScript.URL_Fetch.URLFetchRequestOptions} */
  const params = {
    contentType : "application/json",
    headers : {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
    method : "get"
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri, params);

  const successChecker = getSuccessChecker();

  const success = successChecker(response);

  if(!success) {
    return {};
  }

  return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
};
```

Map it over the list of script files you obtained using ziganotschka's method, and you will get detailed info about the projects. Next, if by *using* you mean *running* projects, you can invoke the `processes.list` [API method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes/list) instead:

```
GET https://script.googleapis.com/v1/processes
```

Required OAuth scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.processes`.

```
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *  projectName : string,
 *  functionName : string,
 *  processType : string,
 *  processStatus : string,
 *  userAccessLevel : string,
 *  startTime : string,
 *  duration : string
 * }} ScriptProcess
 * 
 * @summary lists script processes for a user
 * @param {{
 *  id : (string|"any"),
 *  pageSize : (number|50),
 *  token : string,
 *  start : (Date|undefined),
 *  end : (Date|undefined),
 *  statuses : string[],
 *  types : string[]
 * }} 
 * @returns {ScriptProcess[]}
 */
const listScriptProcesses = ({
  id = ScriptApp.getScriptId(),
  token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
  pageSize = 50,
  start, end,
  statuses = [],
  types = []
} = {}) => {

  const query = [
    `pageSize=${pageSize}`,
    `userProcessFilter.startTime=${toZuluTimestamp(start)}`,
    `userProcessFilter.endTime=${toZuluTimestamp(end)}`
  ];

  id !== "any" && query.push(`userProcessFilter.scriptId=${id}`);
  types.length && query.push(`userProcessFilter.types=${types.join(",")}`);
  statuses.length && query.push(`userProcessFilter.statuses=${statuses.join(",")}`);

  const uri = `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/processes?${query.join("&")}`;

  /** @type {GoogleAppsScript.URL_Fetch.URLFetchRequestOptions} */
  const params = {
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "get"
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri, params);
  const content = response.getContentText();

  const successChecker = getSuccessChecker();
  const success = successChecker(response);

  if (!success) {
    console.warn(response.getResponseCode(), content);
    return [];
  }

  const { processes = [] } = JSON.parse(content);

  return processes;
};
```

In response, you will get metadata about script executions *on behalf* of the user whose credentials are passed with the bearer token (you will need a service account for each user).

The rest is easy: if the response is not empty, then the user ran a script project at some point in time (note that the utility above defaults both `start` and `end` timestamp parameters to `now`). If you supply `any` as the script Id, the request will return *every* execution made on behalf of the user.

An added benefit of the approach is that *every* type of script project execution is returned, including Web Apps, Add-ons, and bound projects (see [`ProcessType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes#ProcessType) enum for details).

The only difficulty with this approach is presented by Web Apps deployed to "execute as me" which will always run under the authority of the script project owner, so you will have to track the users of the Web App separately.

---

Snippets above use the following utility scripts:

```
/**
 * @summary checks HTTPResponse for being successful
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.URL_Fetch.HTTPResponse} resp 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
const getSuccessChecker = ({ successOn = [200] } = {}) => (resp) => {
    const code = resp.getResponseCode();
    return successOn.some(c => c === code);
};
```

```
/**
 * @summary converts input into RFC3339 UTC "Zulu" format
 * @param {Date|number|string} [date] 
 * @returns {string}
 */
const toZuluTimestamp = (date = Date.now()) => new Date(date).toISOString().replace('Z','000000Z');
```

---

You will need to enable [V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#incompatibilities) enabled for the snippets above to work (or transpile them to ES5 syntax).