# can I set/change the owner Google Calendar event using an Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I wrote the following function in Apps Script to create a Calendar Event (based on information in a Google Sheet), but would like one of the attendees to be the owner so they can see the waiting room for guests. Can I transfer ownership of the event or is there another way to make that happen?

```
function createEvent(title,start,end,teacher,student) {
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar
  // https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events
  var event = {
    summary: title,
    description: 'Teacher / student meeting',
    start: {
      dateTime: start.toISOString()
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: end.toISOString()
    },
    guestsCanInviteOthers: "no",
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: "hangoutsMeet"
        },
        requestId: start,
      },
    },
    attendees: [
    {email: teacher},
    {email: student}
    ],
  };
    event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId, {sendNotifications: false, conferenceDataVersion: 1} );
  return event.id;
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to assign the event ownership to a different user

**1. Transfer the ownership of an already existing event**

- This is unfortunately not possible by setting the `creator` or `organizer` property, since those parameters are only [read-only](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations).
- To transfer the ownership, you need to use the method [Events: move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move). Note that in this case the event will be moved out of the calendar it is currently located into the calendar of the person who is meant be asisgned as the new owner

**2. Use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)**

- This allows you perform requests on behalf of any user of your domain
- In other words, you can create events on another user's behalf by impersonating him.
- In Apps Script you do so by using the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2)
- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342311/how-to-get-a-list-of-g-suite-users-which-are-using-google-apps-script/63392311#63392311) for a sample

Comment: I am interested in using the second bullet of the first point. I have looked into using the Events: move method, but have not been able to get that working. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong in the code below?


`function move(event_id) {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();;
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  if (!event_id) {
    event_id = "567031pjq65e18o9nj92vos050";
  }
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, event_id, {});
  Calendar.Events.move(calendarId, event_id, "email@domain.com");
}`

Comment: update:
Ah, you need to have writing access for the other calendar as well. So maybe a service account with domain-wide delegation will do the trick there as well.

Comment: Yes, it will also do the trick. However, when using a service account you need to to build your request differently than in your comment. You need to build a `service` and then perform a UrlFetch request to https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId  with `service.getAccessToken()` for authentication INSTEAD of Calendar.Events.get. It is a very different process. See the sample I linked in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @ziganotschka I appreciate it very much.
What am I doing wrong here? https://pastebin.com/eD5rja6n

Comment: having issues logging back into pastebin, so here's an updated code (though it gives me an error 404 currently, at least there's some progress): https://wtools.io/paste-code/b2Jr

Comment: Does `user` have editor access to the calendar?

Comment: The service account has editor access to all calendars in the domain. The user is a service account user linked to the service account.

Comment: When you use impersonation it is not relevant either the service account has editor access to the calendar. It is the impersonated user who needs to have editor access to the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`guestsCanSeeOtherGuests`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#guestsCanSeeOtherGuests) property to `true`.

```
var event = {
  // ... 
  guestsCanInviteOthers: false, // expected a boolean, not the string "no"
  guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: true
};
```

If using [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app), you can call [`.setGuestsCanSeeGuests(true)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setguestscanseeguestsguestscanseeguests) on the [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event).