# Transfering the ownership of a calendar event to another user

Tags: google-apps-script, events, calendar, transfer, ownership

I'm trying to create a script to transfer the ownership of a calendar event, created by me, to another user. Actually, I have a script to create a large set of events automatically from a google sheet. The events are created succesfully. Each event has an organiser and I want to transfer the ownership of the calendar events to them, for being capable to add another guests, change the information or details of the event, add files, etc.

Normally, I have to use the "three dots" in each calendar event to transfer the event, look for the desired ownership, and paste the text to invite them to accept the ownership of the created event.

I think this whould be possible with an Google Apps Script, but I cannot find any information about this, except for some pages indicating you must have some editor privileges on the receptor's calendar, or similar. This is not the case.

I'm expecting a way to do this automatically. It would avoid me a lot of time, because now I have to make it by hand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can I set/change the owner Google Calendar event using an Apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988819/can-i-set-change-the-owner-google-calendar-event-using-an-apps-script)

Comment: No, @Tedinoz. They say that you need to have edit access to both calendars. But the only I want is to send another user an invitation to be the owner of the event I've created. This is very simple in Calendar, with the three dots and the option "Change owner". I think there should be the manner to do exactly the same with GAS, only knowing the email of the new organiser of the event.

Comment: I don't promise that this is a/the solution but consider this. Calendar API [Organisers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#organizers) => `Events have a single organizer which is the calendar containing the main copy of the event.` Method [move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/move) => `Moves an event to another calendar, i.e. changes an event's organizer.` You can test this with the APIs Explorer.